# wxPython StaticText Issue in my Code

Tags: python, wxpython

There's an issue in this bit of wxPython code I have, the StaticText causes everything else to seemingly disappear.

Note: This is my first time using wxPython and I'm very novice at programming in general, so please try to give a clear explanation. Thanks!

```
import wx

APP_EXIT = 1
pos1 = (150, 200)

class scoutingSet(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(scoutingSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

         ############################################################
         # MENUBARS AND MENUITEMS
         menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
         fileMenu = wx.Menu()
         fileMenu2 = wx.Menu()

         openSheet = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, wx.ID_ANY, 'Open')
         openSheet.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('open.png'))
         fileMenu.AppendItem(openSheet)
         fileMenu.AppendSeparator()

         saveSheet = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, wx.ID_ANY, 'Save')
         saveSheet.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('save.png'))
         fileMenu.AppendItem(saveSheet)
         fileMenu.AppendSeparator()

         quitSheet = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, APP_EXIT, 'Quit')
         quitSheet.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('close.png'))
         fileMenu.AppendItem(quitSheet)
         self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, id=APP_EXIT)

         fileMenu2.Append(100, '&About')
         self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.aboutBox, id=100)

         menuBar.Append(fileMenu, 'File')
         menuBar.Append(fileMenu2, 'Information')
         self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

         ############################################################
         # BUTTONS AND CONTROL

         panel = wx.Panel(self)
         closebutton = wx.Button(panel, label = 'Close\nClose', pos = (20, 30))

         closebutton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)

         ############################################################
         # STATIC TEXTS


         ############################################################
         # TEXT CONTROL BOXES


         wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = pos1, size = (50, 50))
         wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (300, 400), size = (50, 50))

         ############################################################
         # SETTINGS

         self.stuff(self)

         self.Maximize()
         self.SetTitle('Scouting Sheet')
         self.Centre()
         self.Show(True)

         ############################################################

         # Quitting

    def OnQuit(self, e):
        self.Close()

    # Info in 

    def aboutBox(self, e):
        desc = """This is the SOTAbots 2014 scouting sheet for the FRC 2014 game Aerial Assist"""

        infoInAbout = wx.AboutDialogInfo()
        infoInAbout.SetIcon(wx.Icon('scouting.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG))
        infoInAbout.SetName('Scouting Sheet')
        infoInAbout.SetVersion('1.0')
        infoInAbout.SetDescription(desc)
        infoInAbout.AddDeveloper('Franklin Lyon\nLucas Grillos')
        wx.AboutBox(infoInAbout)

    def stuff(self, e):
        textpnl = wx.StaticText(self,-1 , label='Watermark', pos=(20, 30))
        textpnl.SetForegroundColour('white')
        textpnl.SetBackgroundColour('blue')

def main():
    ex = wx.App()
    scoutingSet(None)
    ex.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note: I put the Static Text in a function, but even inside the InitUI function, the issue persists. It has to do with the StaticText being shown because if I comment out the call everything displays fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think wx.StaticText is put on self (wx.Frame) rather than the panel, although wx.TextCtrl are on the panel. What happens if you put wx.StaticText on the panel?

Also, I think you need a Sizer (ex. wx.BoxSizer) to manage the layout.  You can find a tutorial about wx.BoxSizer at http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/. In initUI, I will do something like:

```
 txtctrl1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = pos1, size = (50, 50))
 txtctrl2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (300, 400), size = (50, 50))
 textpnl = wx.StaticText(panel,-1 , label='Watermark', pos=(20, 30))

 vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
 vbox.add(txtctrl1, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
 vbox.add(txtctrl2, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
 vbox.add(textpnl , 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
 vbox.add(closebutton, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

 panel.SetSizer(vbox)
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: How would I add the wx.StaticText to the panel?

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, figured it out. I should have more carefully read what you said. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. When there is only one widget placed on the Frame, wxpython will automatically wrap it with a sizer and fit it to the Frame. But if there are more than one, layout needs to be manually handled by user using sizer. I think that's what happened. Can you also accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You GUI components are not properly laid out. I recommend you to use [sizers](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html) for a proper layout. [BoxSizer](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.BoxSizer-class.html) are simple to play with. Here is a nice tutorial on [Layout management](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/).

Your code will work when you provide the size of the `panel`. Use this line `panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(800,800))` now you shall see all your components! I also changed the position of your static text, because it was being overlapped with the button.

Please note that you should discourage using names like `panel` in your code. Instead use something like `myPanel` or `panelA` etc.

**Working code**: Tested on Windows 8, wxPython v3.0

```
import wx

APP_EXIT = 1
pos1 = (150, 200)

class scoutingSet(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(scoutingSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

         ############################################################
         # MENUBARS AND MENUITEMS
         menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
         fileMenu = wx.Menu()
         fileMenu2 = wx.Menu()

         openSheet = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, wx.ID_ANY, 'Open')
         openSheet.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('open.png'))
         fileMenu.AppendItem(openSheet)
         fileMenu.AppendSeparator()

         saveSheet = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, wx.ID_ANY, 'Save')
         saveSheet.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('save.png'))
         fileMenu.AppendItem(saveSheet)
         fileMenu.AppendSeparator()

         quitSheet = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, APP_EXIT, 'Quit')
         quitSheet.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('close.png'))
         fileMenu.AppendItem(quitSheet)
         self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, id=APP_EXIT)

         fileMenu2.Append(100, '&About')
         self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.aboutBox, id=100)

         menuBar.Append(fileMenu, 'File')
         menuBar.Append(fileMenu2, 'Information')
         self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

         ############################################################
         # BUTTONS AND CONTROL

         panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(800,800))
         closebutton = wx.Button(panel, label = 'Close\nClose', pos = (20, 30))

         closebutton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)

         ############################################################
         # STATIC TEXTS


         ############################################################
         # TEXT CONTROL BOXES


         wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = pos1, size = (50, 50))
         wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (300, 400), size = (50, 50))

         ############################################################
         # SETTINGS

         self.stuff(self)

         self.Maximize()
         self.SetTitle('Scouting Sheet')
         self.Centre()
         self.Show(True)

         ############################################################

         # Quitting

    def OnQuit(self, e):
        self.Close()

    # Info in 

    def aboutBox(self, e):
        desc = """This is the SOTAbots 2014 scouting sheet for the FRC 2014 game Aerial Assist"""

        infoInAbout = wx.AboutDialogInfo()
        infoInAbout.SetIcon(wx.Icon('scouting.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG))
        infoInAbout.SetName('Scouting Sheet')
        infoInAbout.SetVersion('1.0')
        infoInAbout.SetDescription(desc)
        infoInAbout.AddDeveloper('Franklin Lyon\nLucas Grillos')
        wx.AboutBox(infoInAbout)

    def stuff(self, e):
        textpnl = wx.StaticText(self,-1 , label='Watermark', pos=(100, 100))
        textpnl.SetForegroundColour('white')
        textpnl.SetBackgroundColour('blue')

def main():
    ex = wx.App()
    scoutingSet(None)
    ex.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I hope this was helpful.